# Turning a pl/pgSQL select statement into an insert

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to turn this select query into an insert query to insert the results into another table, but PostgreSQL is telling me no. This query works and returns a 'reports' data type:

```
drop function counties();

create or replace function counties()
returns table(code varchar(16), county varchar(50), count bigint) as $$
DECLARE
    new_version_number varchar(50) := concat('gcversa00', MAX("versionnumber")) from "gcdefault"."versionhistory";
    old_version_number varchar(50) := concat('gcversa00', MAX("versionnumber"-2)) from "gcdefault"."versionhistory";
BEGIN RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
format(
    'with cte_current as (select distinct a.code as code, b.countyname as county from %I.servicearea a, public.counties b 
                 where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) = True group by a.code, b.countyname),

         cte_new     as (select distinct a.code as code, b.countyname as county from %I.servicearea a, public.counties b 
                 where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) = True group by a.code, b.countyname),


        cte_union as (select code, county from cte_current
        union all
        select code, county from cte_new)

    select code,county, count(*) as count
    from cte_union
    group by code, county
    Having count (*) <> 2', new_version_number, old_version_number
    );
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I turn this into an insert query and call `select counties()`:

```
drop function counties();

create or replace function counties()
returns table(code varchar(16), county varchar(50), count bigint) as $$
DECLARE
    new_version_number varchar(50) := concat('gcversa00', MAX("versionnumber")) from "gcdefault"."versionhistory";
        old_version_number varchar(50) := concat('gcversa00', MAX("versionnumber"-2)) from "gcdefault"."versionhistory";
BEGIN RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
format(
    '
    with cte_current as (select distinct a.code as code, b.countyname as county from %I.servicearea a, public.counties b 
                 where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) = True group by a.code, b.countyname),

         cte_new     as (select distinct a.code as code, b.countyname as county from %I.servicearea a, public.counties b 
                 where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) = True group by a.code, b.countyname),


        cte_union as (select code, county from cte_current
        union all
        select code, county from cte_new)

    insert into county_check (code, county, count)
    select code, county, count(*) as count from cte_union
    group by code, county
    Having count (*) <> 2', new_version_number, old_version_number
    );
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR:  cannot open INSERT query as cursor
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function counties() line 5 at RETURN QUERY
```

How can I make this work as an insert statement similar to the way I have it laid out now (if possible)? I looked at creating some temp tables instead of using the cte's in the query, and then using a `select into` loop, but I can't find any examples this complex that I can use.

Comment: why not `insert into county_check (code, county, count) select * from counties()`?..

Comment: I got the same result when trying this.

Comment: hm - that's odd. the first version works with select, but does not when you insert select from it?..

Comment: never mind, this worked. I was using the second function instead of the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `RETURNING` to fix it (to actually return declared return type), eg:

```
t=# create table so(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create or replace function f() returns table (i int) as
$$
begin
return query execute format ('
with c(c) as (select 2)
, i as (insert into so select c from c returning *)
select * from i');
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
t=# select f();
 f
---
 2
t=# select * from so;
 i
---
 2
(1 row)
```

but in your case why not just:

```
insert into county_check (code, county, count) select * from counties()
```

Comment: sure, no worries